# Terminal won't update execution files

Tags: linux, makefile, terminal, compilation, execute

I'm having trouble with executing code on my terminal, every time I try to make or execute a file it would say file up to date or when I do the gcc... method it doesn't update either.

```
major2 %  gcc shell2.c -lreadline
major2 % make shell              
make: `shell' is up to date.
```

Comment: What do you think `make shell` should be doing here?  Do you have a makefile?  Presumably you already have an existing file or directory `shell`, so unless you have a makefile telling make to do something different, nothing will happen; as make tells you, the target is up to date already.

Comment: Well I normally just type in make "file" and without having an actual makefile it compiles the code for me, I'm not familiar with how this works my professor showed it to us in class once and have been just using it ever since. And yes shell is a shell.c file, I normally just type "make shell" without the extension and to my understanding it "updates" the execution code

Comment: What it will do is compare the last modified time of your `shell.c` file with the last modified time of the `shell` executable.  If the source file is newer, it will rebuild the `shell` executable according to some default built-in rules.  If the source file is not newer, it won't do anything because `shell` is already up to date (as far as make can tell with the information it has).  That's why you see _is up to date_.